# Is there a limit on number of SQL Server column master keys / column encryption keys used in 'Always Encrypted'?

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2016, capacity, always-encrypted

For certain capacity design needs I am interested in qualitative figures regarding the limit on number of SQL Server encryption keys (both MASTER and COLUMN).

Looking at various "Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server" references - surprisingly - no official documentation is given.

Does anybody have an idea?

---

Sorry... I am afraid that I missed something here.

Following reference lists physical limitation on various number of objects:

Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

For example:
Columns per table is limited to 1,024.
Nonclustered indexes per table is limited to 999
Etc...

Similarly - I wonder how many CMK-s and CEK-s used for 'Always Encrypted' can be maintained in a given database.
These figures are not  given there.

As opposed to the given answer - a database can have more than a single Column MASTER Encryption key.
The queries below are applied on my AEdemo database.

select [name] from  sys.column_master_keys cmk

-- name

---

--ColMasterKey
--ColMasterKey_1
--CMK1

select [name] from sys.column_encryption_keys cek

-- name

---

-- ColEncryptionKey
-- CEK1
-- TeamDemoKey

Comment: A database can only have 1 `MASTER` key; so you have a limitation there. I don't believe, however, there is a limit to the number of objects a database can have, and a key is still an object. If there is a limit, I wouldn't be surprised is at the limit of one of the datatypes, such as `bigint` (at 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) or `uniqueidentifier` (which can have a far larger number of different values).

Comment: Correction, there *is* a limit to the number of objects, I missed it:  2,147,483,647 (so the `int` data type max value).

Comment: Encryption keys do not live in the database object table. Instead they live in `sysclsobjs`, which contain such varied other things as assemblies, backup devices, full-text catalogs, partition functions/schemes and file groups. Although the type of the `id` column of that table is `int`, this does not mean that the full range of 2^31-1 objects is necessarily supported, although that does provide an absolute upper limit. (For example, there is a documented limit of 32767 file groups per database, far less than the table allows.) In short: without docs we don't know.